# Comparing what's in a variable to text?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I'm attempting to do some data validation and am trying to use an if statement to see if what is in the variable ERROR-FLAG and RECORD-CODE is "NO" and "VC". Example below..

```
       MOVE "NO"                   TO ERROR-FLAG.
       MOVE "NO"                   TO ERROR-FLAG2.
       IF VEND-NUM = SPACES
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "********" TO BC-AST-OUT
           MOVE "B"  TO B-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.
       IF VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC AND ERROR-FLAG IS NOO
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "********" TO BC-AST-OUT
           MOVE "C"  TO C-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.
       IF RECORD-CODE IS NOT VC
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "**" TO A-AST-OUT
           MOVE "A"  TO A-ERROR-OUT

       END-IF.
```

`NOO` AND `VC` are defined in the working storage as "NO" and "VC" respectively. I can't seem to figure this out, any and all help is much appreciated! I'm not sure if it matters but VEND-NUM and RECORD-CODE are read in.

```
Error code
   176  IGYPS2074-S   "NOO" was defined as a type that was invalid in this     context.  The statement was discarded.

                  Same message on line:    195    205    210    224

   181  IGYPS2074-S   "VC" was defined as a type that was invalid in this context.  The statement was discarded.
```

I want it to determine if ERROR-FLAG IS "NO" or not. If it's "NO" I want it to do the following move instructions for the if.

Comment: what exactly is happening and what are you expecting to happen ???, at the moment the question is to broad.

Comment: Error code `   176  IGYPS2074-S   "NOO" was defined as a type that was invalid in this context.  The statement was discarded.
 
                      Same message on line:    195    205    210    224
 
   181  IGYPS2074-S   "VC" was defined as a type that was invalid in this context.  The statement was discarded.`

Comment: well what is the definition of NOO, VC, Record-code etc ???

Comment: Record code is read in.  PIC XX, NOO is defined as "No" and VC is defined as "VC"

Comment: Shouldn't you be using "is equal" (or just =)  and not just IS !!!

Comment: and of-course  is not equals (or just not =) instead of IS NOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using NOO as if it was a CLASS. I will skip what a CLASS is here (but NUMERIC is a CLASS that regroup numeric values "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" for example). I will just explain how to compile your code and make it easier to read and understand.

I will give you a solution for "ERROR-FLAG" and "NOO", it is the same for "RECORD-CODE" and "VC".

Here you want to test if the value of "ERROR-FLAG" is equal to "NOO". In COBOL you could literally write:

```
IF VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC AND ERROR-FLAG IS EQUAL TO NOO
```

Also it is may be easier to read this way:

```
IF VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC AND ERROR-FLAG = NOO
```

This is strictly the same.

In order to make your code more maintainable, I strongly recommend you to use parenthesis like this:

```
IF (VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC) AND (ERROR-FLAG = NOO)
```

Finally, COBOL gives you a great tool: level-88 declaration. In your case, you could declare a level-88 value on ERROR-FLAG like this:

```
01 ERROR-FLAG           PIC X(02).
   88 ERROR-FLAG-NOO    value 'NO'.
```

In this case, when "ERROR-FLAG" contains the value "NO", then ERROR-FLAG-NOO is true (it works like a boolean).

Your IF statement could then be:

```
IF (VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC) AND (ERROR-FLAG-NOO)
```

That is for the first step: be able to compile your program and make it a bit easier to understand through level-88 values. In a second time, you could use an EVALUATE statement. In you second IF statement you are testing if ERROR-FLAG is "NO" because you don't want to do the second test if the first one is not correct. You could do:

```
EVALUTE TRUE
   WHEN VEND-NUM = SPACES
        ...
   WHEN VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC
        ...
   WHEN RECORD-CODE NOT = VC
        ...
   WHEN OTHER
        ...
END-EVALUATE
```

In this case, if the first WHEN is true, the code following the when (which I wrote "...") will be executed. The following WHEN will not be tested and the EVALUATE statement will go to "END-EVALUATE". If the first WHEN statement is false, the second WHEN statement will be tested. And so on. If all the WHEN statements are false, the "WHEN OTHER" statement will always be executed. You can find documentation on EVALUATE statement fairly easily on the internet.

Comment: I edited for 0 as part of NUMERIC. 
What I meant for the optimizer is that (at least for IBM COBOL) there are no guaranties that IF are test in the order they are written. In this: "VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC AND ERROR-FLAG = NOO", "ERROR-FLAG = NOO" may be tested first. Without parenthesis, it could change some results. Also, I admit, not in this case. 
I used NOO to be consistent with the first message.

Comment: No. That is not correct. The order that an IF (or any condition) is evaluated in is documented, and it is entirely unaffected by optimisation. Think about it. `IF A NUMERIC AND A EQUAL TO ZERO`. If the second test were done first, there could be a S0C7. This is not just for IBM COBOL, the order of evaluation is in the COBOL Standard. I always use parenthesis anyway, as I want humans to be able to understand the order. The compiler always get it correct from what we write, but people don't always write them correctly :-) No optimisation for order of IF which can change the result of the IF.

Comment: I am really interested in any documentation about this. I accually had a problem with this king of statement: IF (IND > ZERO) AND (MY-TAB(IND) = 10) where MY-TAB(0) was once accessed. I was asked to change it to IF IND > ZERO THEN IF MY-TAB(IND) = 10 THEN ... END-IF END-IF.

Comment: P294 of the Enterprise COBOL Language Reference, Order of evaluation of conditions

Comment: Without seeing the original code and the data I can't say what your problem was, but it was not what you were told. Programs just plain wouldn't work if the order of the evaluation of a complex condition were mucked-about with by optimisation :-)

Comment: For the COBOL Standard, here's a link to a draft (not much change since) and it is 8.8.4.2 you want to read from. You'll see what I mean about it being the same. The actual Standard costs money, so file this one away for your own use.

Answer (score 3):

In your `IF` statements, you are using `NOO` and `VC` as though they were `88`-level condition names or a "class test" that you can define using `SPECIAL-NAMES`.

As Bruce Martin has pointed out, one way is to use `IS EQUAL TO`/`IS NOT EQUAL` TO in your IF statements.

The clearer way is to actually use 88's. An example.

```
01  FILLER PIC X VALUE SPACE.
    88  DATA-IN-ERROR VALUE "Y".
    88  DATA-NOT-IN-ERROR VALUE "N".

SET DATA-NOT-IN-ERROR TO TRUE
IF VEND-NUM = SPACES
    SET DATA-IN-ERROR TO TRUE
    MOVE "********" TO BC-AST-OUT
    MOVE "B"  TO B-ERROR-OUT
END-IF

IF VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC 
AND DATA-NOT-IN-ERROR
    ...
END-IF
```

The names are for illustrating this, and can be improved for your situation.

A fuller example:

```
       05  RECORD-CODE                 PIC XX.
           88  RECORD-CODE-IS-VC       VALUE "VC".

   ...       

   01  FILLER                          PIC X.
       88  ERROR-FOUND                 VALUE "Y".
       88  ERROR-FOUND-FALSE           VALUE "N".

   SET FIRST-ERROR-FOUND-FALSE TO TRUE

   IF VEND-NUM = SPACES
       SET FIRST-ERROR-FOUND   TO TRUE
       MOVE "********" TO BC-AST-OUT
       MOVE "B"  TO B-ERROR-OUT
   END-IF

   IF VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC 
   AND FIRST-ERROR-FOUND-FALSE
       SET ERROR-FOUND         TO TRUE
       MOVE "********" TO BC-AST-OUT
       MOVE "C"  TO C-ERROR-OUT
   END-IF

   IF NOT RECORD-CODE-IS-VC
       SET ERROR-FOUND         TO TRUE
       MOVE "**"               TO A-AST-OUT
       MOVE "A"                TO A-ERROR-OUT
   END-IF
```

Further re-working:

```
   EVALUATE TRUE
       WHEN VEND-NUM = SPACES
           MOVE "********"     TO BC-AST-OUT
           MOVE "B"            TO B-ERROR-OUT
       WHEN VEND-NUM NOT NUMERIC
           MOVE "********"     TO BC-AST-OUT
           MOVE "C"            TO B-ERROR-OUT
       WHEN NOT RECORD-CODE-IS-VC
           MOVE "**"           TO A-AST-OUT
           MOVE "A"            TO A-ERROR-OUT
   END-EVALUATE
```

If you need the error-code for elsewhere, simply insert the SET statement.